# PHP not uploading CSV file, but other formats

Tags: php, csv, upload

This is my form in wich I'm asking for a file:

```
<form action="controllers/controller-Product.php?action=import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Select your CSV File<br/>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Continue to import"/>

</form>
```

In the action (controller-Product.php) I have this line of code:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
```

**If I choose a JPG or a PNG or even a PDF file, it shows me all its properties.**

When I choose a **CSV** file, it just ignores it and the var_dump function returns an empty array.

[image]

Any ideas why the CSV File is being ignored?

**IMPORTANT; EDIT**
What I'm showing here are two files, the one that contains the HTML form and the action file which only contains that line of PHP code. There are those two files only and there is no more code doing anything before the var_dump() line. All these files are as raw as you see here.

Comment: Need more of your code

Comment: That's actually all the code, I am just testing everything's working before I start coding a module in which I need to import a CSV file into a MySQL Database. The HTML code is exactly that and the action (controller-Product.php) executes only that line.

Comment: Check the file size and the maximum upload size

Comment: In my PHP.ini file, the upload_max_filesize property is set to 64M, and the file is 3,150 Kb only.

Comment: Any chance that the problem may lie in your PHP handler?

Comment: @Fred-ii- excuse me sir. What do you my by handler? the file that is receiving the file? you mean, the form's action?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You may have some type of constraint in there. It's hard to properly diagnose a problem with just `var_dump($_FILES);` or is that your entire code for the PHP / handler file => `controllers/controller-Product.php?action=import`

Comment: have you check whether your server can accept '*.csv' files ?

Comment: @Moch.Rasyid how can I achieve that? Where do I check?  thank you

Comment: You're not showing us enough code to be able to help. Well, not for me anyway. This `action=import` you obviously have some code in your PHP that you're not sharing, along with a GET statement. Good luck with that.

Comment: Fred, the "action" parameter there is nothing, there is no more code in the PHP file that is receiving the file (controller-Product.php), that's because when this is working, I am gonna put some more code that requires to check the action parameter. But for now, it's just there floating doing nothing and the output of the current only line of code I have is being shown in the question.

Comment: Have you checked your error log?

Comment: This is what the error log shows in the last lines: [29-Sep-2014 03:25:05 Europe/Paris] PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 3228024 bytes exceeds the limit of 3145728 bytes in Unknown on line 0 --------by the way, why is there the Europe/Paris time zone? :S that's weird!

Comment: So there's your answer ;)

Where is your server?

Comment: Colombia, south america. I reinstalled WAMP and I have to fix this

Answer (score 3):

Silly problem solved:

In the PHP.INI file you gotta search for:

```
post_max_size = 3M
```

And change it's default value

Instead of

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

The file I was trying to upload in CSV format was more than 3MB, that's why the server was ignoring it.